# MacOS Ventura on KVM/OpenCore - unable to set 1920x1080 resolution

Tags: macos, resolution, kvm-switch

https://github.com/kholia/OSX-KVM

Correct resolution (1920x1080) has been set in OpenCore config.plist. It actually works - OpenCore starts with 1920x1080 resolution. However, MacOS itself boots with screen resolution 1600x900. MacOS screen resolution settings includes only 3 predefined options, large, default, small, but choosing any of them breaks my installation (I'm getting black screen with only small portion visible).

Any ideas how to force macos to use resolution set in OpenCore? Older MacOS version work just fine, problem started on MacOS 13 Ventura.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed the device from vga to virtio and MacOS Venture is now 1920x1080

```
# -device VGA,vgamem_mb=128
-device virtio-vga
```